# How do I make it so that my website users can write in a box?

Tags: css, text

I am creating a log in div where people can put in their password and Email but I don't know how to make it so that they can write in the div. Could anyone tell me how?

Comment: wondering why can't you use Html controls?...like textbox, password etc...

Comment: Both this and your other question show that you do absolutely no research on your own. This is BASIC HTML! Surely if you've already made a basic page, you should know about `<input />`...

Answer (score 3):

You're referring to ContentEditable

http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

```
<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true">
  Editable text here
</div>
```

Do NOT use this for password fields. That's just silly. The whole point of `<input type="password">` is that it masks the input. You'd have to use a special `onkeyup` handler to swap the character with an asterisk and then copy the innerHTML to a js object or save in a data-val attribute or something. Don't re-invent the wheel here.

You can style your `input` fields to look pretty much like any div element anyway these days.